# R - in backward regression, can you choose how many variables will stay in final model?

Tags: r, variables, regression

In backward regression, can you choose how many variables will stay in final model? Let's say you have 50 variables in regression but you want maximum of 10 to stay in the model. How to achieve it?

Comment: There is no argument that explicitly does that. Although you can look up the source code and add a condition that ensures a maximum of ten variables.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean, how to ensure that in the source code?

Comment: You'll have to add a condition that does that. I'm guessing you'll be using MASS package's `step`  function to do this. You can get the source code easily. Copy the code and make changes and try using the new function